# Filter what datagrid elements to add to stringbuilder

Tags: c#, csv, file-io, datagrid

my app has an export button which opens a save file dialog and a drop down box allowing the user to select a client and the path to save the file to , upon clicking the export button I want to take the data from the data grid where the client name matches that found in the drop down and send these to the file , at the moment my code is as follows however it only returns the headings for the columns , would anyone know a solution ? :

```
      foreach (DataRow dr in this.CalcDataSet.MInve)
        {

            bool hasValue = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < dr.ItemArray.Count(); i++)
            {
                //if doesnt match selected client
                if    (!dr[i].ToString().Contains(dropboxClientList.SelectedValue.ToString()))
                hasValue = true;
            }

            //else 
            if (!hasValue) rowsToADD.Add(dr);

            foreach (DataRow field in rowsToADD)
            {   
              str.Append(field.ToString() + ",");
            }
            str.Replace(",", "\n", str.Length - 1, 1);
        }


        try
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Filepath, str.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Write Error :" + ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: what is CalcDataSet.MInve?

Comment: its a datasource , or a dataset might be clearer , the Minve is the Master Inventory List  , I dont think they'd have anythin to do with it though as I can easily take all of the data from the Master inventory table and add that to the data grid and then the file , the problem arises when I try to only add the selected rows

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457197/c-sharp-datagridview-to-text-file)

```
string file_name = "C:\\test1.txt";

System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;

objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file_name);

int count = dgv.Rows.Count;

for (int row = 0; row < count; row++)
{
    int colCount = dgv.Rows[row].Cells.Count;

    // EDIT inserted if statement
    string selectedValue = dropboxClientList.SelectedValue.ToString();
    string clientName = dgv.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

    // If the current row contains the selected client name 
    if (clientName.Contains(selectedValue)
    {
        // Write the columns for the current row
        for ( int col = 0; col < colCount; col++)  
        {            
            objWriter.WriteLine(dgv.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.ToString());
        }
    }

    // record seperator could be written here.
}

objWriter.Close();
```

Comment: sorry about this , havin a blonde moment but I cant work out how that code would work in relation to the question ? i have a drop down box , when the export button is hit I need to reference the box , and only write the data grid rows whose client name is equal to the selected one

Comment: Would the '// EDIT inserted if statement' new code work for you? Change the cell reference (clientName) accordingly.

Comment: By the way 'dgv' relates to the DataGridView name, not a dataset, datarow or anything else